# Toggling between Two Images on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

This question is kind of similar in some ways to others already out there, but also unique in its own way.

My ultimate goal is to have an on/off switch that is able to toggle between images and text. For example, in the "ON" State, the button will display a green circle and the text "Your app is running". In the "OFF" State, the button will display a red circle and the text "Your app is off".

Any recommendations on how to go about doing this? Ideally I would like this to use a combination of HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

Comment: Show what you have done so far

Comment: Please don't just supply some requirements and expect code in return. StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please show how you've attempted to solve the problem explaining how and where you have fallen short. For more info take the [tour] and read [help]

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do. Just create a button and change its style and text.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const button = document.getElementById('myButton');
  
  if (button.innerHTML === 'Turn on') {
    button.innerHTML = 'Turn Off';
    button.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    button.innerHTML = 'Turn on';
    button.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
}
```

```css
#myButton {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: none;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="myButton" onClick='myFunction()'>Turn on</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what your goal is. If I got it correctly, I think you can do it without JavaScript. The technic is called CSS image sprites.

- [CSS Image Sprites - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp)